# Starting debugger error console.assert is not a function

Tags: react-native

My react-native version is the latest `0.71.3`. Whenever I start debugging, I get the error `console.assert is not a function`. Why is this happening and any fix for it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The issue is very likely related to `react-native-reanimated`. There is no fix released yet but a [patch](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3951#issuecomment-1384223013) is available.

Though I noticed that many other problems arise after fixing this specific issue. I solved all my problems by downgrading a major release, from 3.0.2 to 2.14.4:

```
npm install --save react-native-reanimated@2.14.4
```

I'm confident that this should solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I try to install

```
npm install --save react-native-reanimated@2.14.4
```

After running Android again, the app can't open. I have to install  `react-native-reanimated` latest, and the app runs normally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).